# How to add the missing numbers with this code and only doing it when a variable is 0 in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

What this functionality does is that for each priority it will rebalance the percentage (Participacion) in equal parts. The problem occurs in odd cases, for example when there are 3 priorities(Prioridad), you must divide 100 / 3, which gives a result of 33 (and 33 + 33 + 33 = 99 )

What should I add to my code, so that when the result of the division is not 100, the missing numbers are added to the last position, completing the 100.

Example problem 1 : [Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqOl3.gif) : The idea is that the last 33 that you see in the gif is automatically transformed into a 34.Tthis is the code i have so far:

```
rebalance(){
    this.beneficiarios = this.beneficiarios.sort((a, b) =>Number(a.Prioridad) - Number(b.Prioridad)).map((val, i, beneficiarios) => {
      const priorityLenght = this.beneficiarios.filter((a) =>
      Number(a.Prioridad) == Number(val.Prioridad)).map((b) =>
      Number(b.Participacion)).length
        const arrObj = {
          ...val,
          Participacion : 100 / priorityLenght
        }
        return arrObj;
      })
  }
```

Problem 2: In the previous gif you can see that when you press the button, the rebalancing was done for all the priorities (Prioridad), I would like it to be only for those that contain a 0 in percentage (Participacion)

I'm pretty sure that both problems can be solved by adding a couple lines of code to the function I put above, but I lack experience to know what to do

Here a StackBlizz of the proyect: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-v8k1hs?file=src/app/example/user.component.ts

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOJOlW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The word "sintaxis" is not an English word; perhaps you mean "syntax"?

Comment: sorry for the problems. I already added a stackblitz with the code.

Comment: A [mre] should be *minimal*, and contain only the code necessary to demonstrate the issue.  An entire multi-file project is probably too much code.  Also, even though an external link is a nice supplement, it is not a substitute for having the code in the question itself.  Please include a self-contained code example directly in the text of the question (which is another reason why you might want to reduce the amount of code).

Comment: You're asking about an algorithm, which should be expressible in a code snippet similar in size to what you've presented here.  But it doesn't need to be a class method with `this` all over the place; instead you can write a standalone function with some example desired input/outputs.  It will also be helpful if you rename your variables to be meaningful English words, as Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your algorithm. Really just needed a slightly different approach. I changed it to use Math.floor() for participation and then got the diff (100 % length) needed to make the value 100% and added that to the last value. Here is the updated stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-7vj1rr?file=src/app/example/user.component.html

PS: never make method calls in the template due to the overhead the this add each time change detection runs; instead use pure pipes or calculate their value for presentation when the data changes. There was a decimal formatting method being called that I removed.

Comment: Hi bjlasc01, ty very much for your corrections! the algorithm is almost working!! the logic is working perfect, but i need the same logic only applied if in the percents we have 0 in one priority, do u know how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by this "only applied if in the percents we have 0 in one priority"?

Comment: yeah, here! [link]( https://ibb.co/rpBmJsT)

Comment: I found some additional issues with your code in fixing the algo. Your input type was not number and not actually binding to the value in ts file. I added [(ngModel)] to make it bind and changed the input type. I also removed the spinner that shows up for number types with an additional css file. This should all work now. Please upvoe and mark as the answer if this works for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-jwxxqq?file=src/app/example/user.component.ts

Comment: its work perfectly, if i could give you 2 upvotes i will give it to you!!! ty very much, you save my life

Comment: Sure thing. I'll settle for one upvote, if you can.

Comment: i cant, i dont i need 15 points for that, and i only have 5